# Is there a job description or role that fits in between web developer and content manager or webmaster?

Tags: web-development, webmasters

I am a web developer who often gets asked by prospective clients to be available on-call to handle tasks which I consider to be content management.

My aim is always to code myself out of the picture by building sites that are very easy to manage by anyone.

To my mind the term "developer" implies developing something ie. building something, not repetitious webmaster / maintenance / content management - type tasks.

Is there a role or job description that implies a more basic level of website content management, somewhere above "Content Manager" because it probably requires at least HTML skills, which "Content Manager" alone doesn't explicitly require?

Some additional task requests that go along with this role: adding menu tabs, content images, slider images, shop products, audio and YouTube clips and pdfs. Basic page layout using WordPress with or without a page builder, setting up regular emailers.

My aim would be to direct these prospective clients to search for that term instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Content editor, or specialist, might be an appropriate term

Comment: Possibly. Or [web editor](https://webeditorhome.wordpress.com/a-web-editor-by-any-other-name/). It seems rare to find those job descriptions used in conjunction with HTML as a skill requirement, though. I would suggest that possibly the exact job description hasn't found a name yet. I've added some more items to my question. I'll wait for a few more suggestions before deciding whether to mark this as the correct answer (I can't up-vote yet). Thanks codenoire!

Comment: This is probably as close as we're going to get for now, so I've marked it as correct. As at this time - until there's a more exact description - the title or description should probably state the HTML requirement eg. "Content Editor with HTML skills".

Answer (score 0):

One of my clients recently referred to me as their Web Administrator. While I built their website and hadn't planned on being their web admin, I charge the same amount per hour to write code as to close an event registration or post a new blog post. In my opinion, a Web Administrator title would cover the tasks that you list, and infer that some technical knowledge is needed.

I offer Maintenance and Technical Support agreements to clients when I'm done building their sites, since that gives me ongoing income streams, but that's not really a title but rather a service. It is something to suggest to your clients, though, since I've seen "CMS Maintenance" as a service offered on many freelancer websites.

For one of the open source projects that I use, they refer to the non-developers with more knowledge than end-users as Implementers, so that's another possibility.

Comment: I think web administrator could contain both the "web editor" and / or "content editor" roles so it's more general / less-specific than those two. I think it also implies more server / security - related skills, so I'm more in favour of a description with an _ editor suffix. Thanks LMK Web.